# Copy and paste rows that meet a condition to a different workbook at once

Tags: vba, excel, loops, conditional-statements

I would need to past rows from masterfile(thisworkbook) to different workbooks based on id. Issue that I am currently having with my code is that it's too slow to copy and paste all the rows one by one, since the masterfile is quite big and I would like to add more conditions (and workbooks) to my code afterwards.

My current code, copying and pasting rows one by one whenever the condition is met:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim newWorkbookOne As Workbook, newWorkbookTwo As Workbook
    Set newWorkbookOne = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWorkbookTwo = Workbooks.Add
    Dim conditionOne As String, conditionTwo as String
    Set conditionOne = "value1"
    Set conditionTwo = "value2"
    For i = 2 To a
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = conditionOne Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        b = newWorkbookOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        newWorkbookOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        h = newWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        newWorkbookTwo.ActiveSheet.Cells(h + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If
  Next 'something
```

This code is quite time consuming and definately not suitable for larger files. For this reason, I would like to paste all the rows to these new workbooks at once. Does anyone have solution on this matter?

Comment: First you can combine your if statements with or, this will reduce iterations by half. Second why not to use PowerQuery?

Comment: @ygaft OP can't combine the `If` statements with `Or` since the code needs to do two different things depending on which condition is met.

Comment: @DirtyDeffy yeap, you are correct, well then PowerQuery should be the easiest solution...

Answer (score 1):

Start off by making sure that `ScreenUpdating` is turned off like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim newWorkbookOne As Workbook, newWorkbookTwo As Workbook
    Set newWorkbookOne = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWorkbookTwo = Workbooks.Add
    Dim conditionOne As String, conditionTwo as String
    Set conditionOne = "value1"
    Set conditionTwo = "value2"
    For i = 2 To a
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = conditionOne Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        b = newWorkbookOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        newWorkbookOne.ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        h = newWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        newWorkbookTwo.ActiveSheet.Cells(h + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If
  Next 'something
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This should reduce the time consumption drastically.

Furthermore, if you wish to do it differently, you could consider running the first `If` statement through and hide all rows that you dont want to copy. Then copy and paste all visible rows in the relevant range in one go. Then unhide those and run the second `If` statement the same way.
Try it yourself, and let me know if you need help :)

Comment: this actually decreased the processing time from 90 seconds to 25 seconds when having eight different conditions and workbooks.

Comment: Awesome - just by turning off `ScreenUpdating` or did you implement my suggestion aswell?

Comment: Just by turning off ScreenUpdating but I'll try implement your suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

2) You could stick all the rows into an array instead of copying the rows one by one and then insert them all at once when the loop is finished. It's the insertion that takes time, not so much the copying.

Try this:

```
Dim newWorkbookOne As Workbook, newWorkbookTwo As Workbook
Dim conditionOne As String, conditionTwo as String
Dim arr1 (0 to 999) as Variant ' change parameters as required
Dim arr2 (0 to 999) as Variant ' change parameters as required
Dim j as Integer, n as Integer

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set newWorkbookOne = Workbooks.Add
Set newWorkbookTwo = Workbooks.Add

Set conditionOne = "value1"
Set conditionTwo = "value2"
For i = 2 To a
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = conditionOne Then
    arr(j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i)
    j = j + 1
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = nametwo Then
    arr2(n) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i)
    n = n + 1
End If
Next 'something

' Insert the values of the arrays in the two new worksheets here
```

**Edit #1: Inserting the array values**

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' change sheet to what's appropriate

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Rows(lastRow + 1 + i).Value2 = arr(i) ' presupposes the array starts at index 0
Next i
```

Comment: This should do the trick! Do you have any suggestions on how I should insert the rows from the array lists? I can only come up with some sort of loop solution, which (I guess) would offset all the benefits of including the rows to these array lists in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Work. A loop is indeed required since you're copying entire rows. If you were only copying cell content in, say columns 1:5, you could just insert the array content in one go. However, this should not offset all the benefits of using arrays, since your code now switches much less between accessing the given documents, which is a costly operation.